# Regular expression for an integer that's just 0 or any number not starting with 0

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java for regular expressions in a homework assignment. I'm trying to match integers, but they cannot start with zero (unless it is just zero). I'm having trouble with this code, it compiles but it doesn't correctly match any integer of multiple digits (like 44, 52, 23321, and so forth).

```
"^[+|-]?[0{1}|([1-9][0-9]*)]$"
```

EDIT: I found a quick fix, I decided to just create an if statement:

```
if(string.equals("0")) return "string is an integer";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.  It looks like you have `[]` and `()` confused.  Hint: the first bit should be `^[+-]?`.

Comment: I thought [+-] was the same as [+|-]? Also, I tried this string "^[+|-]?[0|([1-9]\\d*)]$", but its still not recognizing any double digit integers (I'm testing 31, for example), but it will recognize any single digits like 0 or 7.

Comment: Umm, not quite.  `[+|-]` matches `+` or `|` or `-`.  Also, your problem is actually the square brackets that you've got enclosing the last 3/4 of your expression.

Comment: Oh, I guess that was my problem then, I assumed the "|" symbol would separate the symbols I wanted to look for, and that it had to be within square brackets. Got it working now, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This is why I said you had `[]` and `()` confused.  `(abc|def)` matches either of the strings "abc" or "def", and if you rearrange the contents of the parentheses that changes what it matches.  `[abc|def]` matches any of the *single characters* `a` `b` `c` `|` `d` `e` `f`, and the order within the square brackets doesn't matter as long as you aren't using shorthands (e.g. `[a-z]` matches any lowercase ASCII letter, but `[az-]` matches only `a`, `z`, and `-`).

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should do the trick:

```
"^[+-]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$"
```

Comment: Please don't give out answers to homework that don't require the poster to think.  Then they don't learn anything.